# Как поменять текст в textview из не главного потока созданного с помощью Thread?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Как поменять текст в textview из не главного потока созданного с помощью Thread?

Comment: Никак, ui контролы обновляются только из ui потока.

Comment: @tym32167 а что тогда делать если мне нужно общаться с сервером в другом потоке и выводить инфу из потока на вью элементы?

Comment: Использовать диспетчер или каким любым другим способом выполнять нужный вам код в ui потоке. Вам же скинули ссылку на дубликат, там все написано